# Diferencia con matrices MATLAB/Python

Tags: python, array, matrices, matlab

Tengo lo siguiente:

- redIdx: una matriz de 2x1 con valores (289485, 289486).
- imagen: matriz de 366x791x3 uint8 (una imagen).
- image2: matriz de ceros con el mismo formato que image.
  En MATLAB, si hago image2 (redIdx) devuelve una matriz 2x1 con valores (0,0) y si hago image (redIdx) devuelve una matriz 2x1 con valores (94, 83).

Pero en Python, si hago image2 [redIdx] o image [redIdx], devuelve el siguiente error: el índice 2879485 está fuera de los límites para el eje 0 con tamaño 366.

¿Cómo puedo obtener el mismo resultado que con MATLAB?

Comment: La principal diferencia entre las matrices de Python y Matlab son los índices. En Matlab comienzan desde 1. En Python comienzan desde 0. En Python ` image2 [redIdx] ` esta una posición después del final de la matriz, en este caso, usa `image2[redIdx-1]`

Comment: El valor de `redIdx` (2879485) está muuuy lejos del tamaño de la matriz (366) para considerarlo un _off by 1_. En cambio veo que está cerca del valor `366*791` (que es 289506). ¿Tal vez quieres usar el valor de `redIdx` como índices dentro de una versión "plana" de la matriz (es decir, una en la que sus valores están almacenados secuencialmente como en un vector, en lugar de en matriz rectangular)?

Comment: por otro lado me han recomendado hacer "linear indexing" @abulafia pero la verdad no sabría cómo implementarlo, no sé si es eso a lo que te refieres

Comment: Probablemente. El problema es que no se sabe qué pretendes hacer exactamente. ¿Quieres tratar los 289506 pixeles de la imagen de 366x791 como una secuencia, y entonces `redIdx` sería el índice dentro de esa secuencia? (Pero entonces los valores que obtendrías serían tuplas de tres componentes, las (r,g,b) del pixel, y no solo unos números como el (93,83) mencionas en la pregunta).

Comment: ¿O bien quieres acceder a cada byte individual de los 868518 (366x791x3) que componen la imagen? En ese caso sí que el resultado serían unos números como (93,83), pero entonces el valor de idx = 2879485 está sospechosamente lejos del máximo posible (868518). Mientras no se aclare qué pretendes exactamente no es posible decir cómo se haría con numpy.

Comment: sii quiero acceder a cada pixel de la imagen exacto, y recomponer la imagen en sus componentes rojo, verde y azul. Creo que el número 2879485 está mal, debe ser 287948 pues me dan los mismos resultados (muy similares) tanto en Python como en Matlab @abulafia

Comment: Pero sigue sin quedar claro. Cada pixel es una terna (r,g,b), por tanto tres números. En cambio en el ejemplo que pones de lo que debe salir (que serían dos pixeles seleccionados a través de idx), dices (93,83), que es como si cada pixel fuese un solo número en vez de un trío. Por tanto parece que no estás accediendo al pixel, sino sólo a una de las componentes del pixel (r, g ó b). Quizás lo mejor sería que explicaras el problema con más detalle. Quizás incluso mostrando el código matlab completo (aunque yo personalmente no sé de matlab quizás otro pueda ayudarte)

Comment: es el mismo problema del otro post @abulafia solo que aquí he reducido bastante la explicación para concretar cuál es el error. El programa en sí es bastante complicado de explicar, simplemente me gustaría que el resultado de Python se asemejara al de Matlab.

Comment: el programa lo que hace es hacer una media de los valores de la imagen original en redIdx (en este caso la media entre 93 y 83) y ese valor se lo asigna a imagen(redIdx). Al final del bucle me quedaría la imagen original en rojo.

Comment: @abulafia entonces cómo podría acceder cada byte individual de los 868518 que componen la imagen? Ya que si en ese caso salen los números que busco me gustaría saber cómo implementarlo, muchas gracias.

Comment: `imagen.flatten()` te devuelve los mismos números que había en `imagen` pero ya sin la "mutidimensionalidad", es decir, los convierte a una ristra (vector). En ella debería funcionar un índice entre 0 y 868517. No obstante habría que saber en qué orden "aplana" matlab las matrices para considerarlas lineales, para asegurar que lo que hace python es lo mismo y por tanto sale el mismo resultado. Numpy admite un parámetro en `flatten()` para especificar el orden. Mira la documentación

Comment: @abufalia vale ahora sí lo he conseguido, ahora una vez asignados esos valores a la imagen de ceros para que se muestre el canal rojo, cómo revierto a la multidimensionalidad para poder mostrar la imagen?

Comment: @abulafia vale haré una nueva pregunta porque realmente está solucionado, ahora tengo el problema del reshape, que se muestra la imagen pero de una manera muy extraña, y si hago lo mismo con greenIdx y blueIdx se muestra la imagen pero como si estuviera desplazada varias veces y dichos desplazamientos se hubieran superpuesto. De todas formas, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda que realmente me ha servido.